# sitecore: editframe

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, page-editor

I need to use editframe to let the front user to modify some checkbox fields

1. I create a new edit frame button and set only those fields that I want front user to edit. For example : Core DB -> /sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/(edit button folder)/(field editor button). In the fields to be edited by front user, I have set it to Headline.
2. In my sublayout, I have this code

   ```
   <sc:EditFrame ID="EditField" runat="server" Buttons="/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/EditFields">
   <div id="whatyoumissed">
       <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
           <LayoutTemplate>
               <ul style="list-style-type: none;" >
                   <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemplaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
               </ul>
           </LayoutTemplate>

           <ItemTemplate>
               <li style="float: left;margin-left:20px;">
                   <sc:FieldRenderer ID="FieldRenderer2" runat="server" FieldName="Headline" 
                   Item="<%# Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item %>" /> <br />
                   <sc:FieldRenderer ID="FR3" runat="server" FieldName="cb" Item="<%# Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item %>" />
               </li>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:ListView>

   </div>
   </sc:EditFrame>
   ```
3. Code behind

   ```
       string queryPath = "/bla/bla/bla/bla/bla/bla/bla/bla/bla";
       var item = sc.Context.Database.GetItem(queryPath);
       var children = item.Children;
       ListView1.DataSource = children;
       ListView1.DataBind();
   ```

When I click on the edit frame in the page editor, the prompted box does not have the field (headline) for me to modify it. Any suggestion?

Answer:
I have google abit of sitecore edit frame datasource and end up with this link
http://blog.jan.hebnes.dk/2011/12/using-sitecore-editframe-with.html

Instead of using the code behind as shown by Martijn Bos, I modify my code from prev to the following.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <ul style="list-style-type: none;" >
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemplaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </ul>
            </LayoutTemplate>

            <ItemTemplate>
                <sc:EditFrame ID="EditField" runat="server" Buttons="/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/EditFields"
                DataSource="<%# ((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem).Paths.FullPath %>" >
                    <li style="float: left;margin-left:20px;">
                        <sc:FieldRenderer ID="FieldRenderer2" runat="server" FieldName="Headline" 
                        Item="<%# Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item %>" /> <br />
                        <sc:FieldRenderer ID="FR3" runat="server" FieldName="cb" Item="<%# Container.DataItem as Sitecore.Data.Items.Item %>" />
                    </li>
                </sc:EditFrame>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried setting the DatasSource of the Editframe?

e.g. `EditField.DataSource = item.Paths.FullPath;`

Comment: And the edit frame would then need to be within the ItemTemplate.

Comment: @techphoria414 do you mean that edit frame only works within a data template? And not working even if I use the sublayout to display other fields from other template by using data binding?

Comment: No I mean that an EditFrame can only edit one item at a time, AFAIK. You got it right.

Answer (score 0):

You almost there. Should not use "FullPath". Try this instead

```
 DataSource="<%# ((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem).Paths.FullPath %>"
```